# Parse Google Speech Kit JSON in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, google-speech-api

I am having the following JSON response from Google speech API

```
    {
    "result": [

    ]
}{
    "result": [
        {
            "alternative": [
                {
                    "transcript": "testing 123"
                },
                {
                    "transcript": "listing 123"
                },
                {
                    "transcript": "casting 123"
                },
                {
                    "transcript": "fasting 123"
                },
                {
                    "transcript": "listing 1 2 3"
                },
                {
                    "transcript": "Justin 123"
                },
                {
                    "transcript": "listening 123"
                },
                {
                    "transcript": "listen 123"
                }
            ],
            "final": true
        }
    ],
    "result_index": 0
}
```

However I am having difficulties in parsing the JSON response. I have the following code

First approach: I get an empty result when I try to print

```
NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = [[results objectForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"result %@", resultsDictionary);
```

Second approach: getting the same empty result when I try to print

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                     options:kNilOptions 
                                                       error:&error];

NSArray* ResultArray = [json objectForKey:@"result"];

NSLog(@"result: %@", ResultArray);
```

Also when I try to validate the JSON response through http://jsonlint.com/, I am getting the following message

```
Parse error on line 5:
...: [            ]}{    "result": [  
--------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response is not in proper json format. First add the below line to remove the extra empty result string by following line:

```
yourJsonString = [yourJsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{\"result\":[]}" withString:@""];
```

Then, Try out the below code:

```
    yourJsonString = [yourJsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{\"result\":[]}" withString:@""];

    NSData* jsonData = [yourJsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *responseObj = [NSJSONSerialization
                                 JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                 options:0
                                 error:&error];

    if(! error) {
        NSArray *responseArray = [responseObj objectForKey:@"result"];
        for (NSDictionary *alternative in responseArray) {
            NSArray *altArray = [alternative objectForKey:@"alternative"];
            for (NSDictionary *transcript in altArray) {
                NSLog(@"transcript : %@",[transcript objectForKey:@"transcript"]);
            }
        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error in parsing JSON");
    }
```